# LabVIEW 2011 missing subvi

Tags: labview

I am trying to load a .vi. While loading, LabVIEW is looking for a vi in `..\National Instruments\Labview 2011\examples\Vision Acquisition\NI-IMAQdx\High Level\SubVIs\`

However, I do not have a "Vision Acquisition" folder in "examples". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [NI-IMAQ drivers](http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/2758/lang/en).

Comment: Thanks. I installed that but Labview still asks for that subvi and I don't have that folder on my system. I now manually pointed it to IMAQ Vision Example folder.vi:
- The VI expected to be at "D:\folder\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2011\examples\Vision Acquisition\NI-IMAQdx\High Level\SubVIs\Flush Control Value.vi" was loaded from "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2011\examples\Vision\IMAQ Vision Example folder.vi".

Where the .vi I try to load is in D:\folder\sub\sub\sub

Answer (score 1):

uninstall it and try to install it again